# Цикличная анимация блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

У меня есть структура карточек

```
<div class=""testimonials-column">
  <div class="testimonials-card">
    Карточка1
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials-card">
    Карточка2
  </div>
  <div class="testimonials-card">
    Карточка3
  </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как мне реализовать такое поведение, чтобы блоки с классом "testimonials-card" с плавной анимацией двигались циклично по вертикали внутри блока "testimonials-column". Такую анимацию еще можно назвать "эффект бегущей строки". Помогите, спасибо!